# What means echo"{@@##}"?

Tags: bash, shell-script

We got a script that we need to understand, and at some point, we got this syntax:

```
if  [ "$PASS_CHAINE" = "TRUE" ]
then echo "Launching DEGAGEMENT" | SLog
     cd $INTERFACE_D/bin_cm/deg
     $INTERFACE_D/bin_cm/deg/lance_deg 2>&1 ; echo "{@@##}RETURN_REAL_STATUS_SCRIPT=${?}" | SLog
     EXIT_CODE=$?
     if [ $EXIT_CODE -ne 0 ]
     then echo "Error in DEGAGEMENT" | SLog
          exit_script
     fi
 fi
```

I'm confused about the `echo "{@@##}"` part, I don't really understand it.
I know the scripts tries to test the return code of the `lance_deg` function, but it won't work because it's gonna get the return code of the echo command.

I can remove the echo part to solve my problem, but the point is really to understand what the `{@@##}` part means.

Comment: `echo "{@@##}"` prints those 6 characters, there's no special meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That part:

```
echo "{@@##}RETURN_REAL_STATUS_SCRIPT=${?}"
```

Just prints:

```
{@@##}RETURN_REAL_STATUS_SCRIPT=x
```

where the last `x` is replaces by the value of variable `$?`. From the bash manpage:

```
   ?      Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.
```

That means that `$?` contains the exit code of the previously executed command: `$INTERFACE_D/bin_cm/deg/lance_deg`, which can be a digit from `0`; for success and `1` or geather for an error.

See this:

```
$ ls file
file
$ echo $? # 0 indicates success
0
$ ls file_not_exist
ls: cannot access file_not_exist: No such file or directory
$ echo $? # >0 is an error
2
```